# Monoid in general dynamic system definition

Tags: dynamical-systems, monoid

I am a newbie in this field but what difference does taking monoid or group in the following definition of dynamic system make?

A tuple
\begin{equation}
(T,M,\phi)
\end{equation}

is called dynamic system, where $T$ is additively written monoid (time), $M$ is a phase space and $\phi$ is an evolution operator

\begin{equation}
\phi = U\subseteq T\times M \rightarrow M
\end{equation}

of the system.

I have found another stronger definiton in which $T$ is said to be additive group.

Does it matter? Is the addition necessarily commutative?

Comment: I am at odds with $T$ being a group. How do you turn back the clock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is whether the time $t$ can only forward or backward as well.  A group has inverses, a monoid does not need them.  In particular, $\mathbb R$ is a group, $[0, \infty)$ (with addition) is not.  If your dynamical system is reversible, you might want to use $\mathbb R$, otherwise only $[0,\infty)$.